# WindowFreeze VCL

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-7, vcl, indy

I have a Delphi7 Project with about 10 windows. The MainWindow gets loaded when the program starts. After a while, the MainWindow accesses another window of the project to add listview items and updates them about ever 1-2 seconds. However this window seems to freeze and doesn't show the listview at all after I opened it.

It works if I have in the OnShow Procedure of my MainWindow the following commands:

```
SecondWindow.Show;
SecondWindow.Close;
```

It works without problems but it seems unprofessional. Any Ideas how I could draw the window without getting showed?

EDIT: CODE (I use Indy9)

```
procedure TMainWindow.ServerSocketExecute(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
begin
 /....
 if Buffer = 'additem' then begin
    Window2.ListView1.Items.Add;
    Exit;
    // .....
 end;
end;
```

That's it. I removed all the timers off Window2 and it seems still to freeze.
Either the mainWindow freezes instantly if an items gets added or when I try to open the 2nd Windows for the first time.

Comment: Very little to go on here. Going to take either a significant improvement to the question or some divine inspiration. Could you show the code that does the updating. Also, how does the 1-2 second updating work? Is that on a timer?

Comment: it is both. I have a timer in the 2nd Form. Even when I remove the timer off the 2nd Form, it doesn't work. The updates of the listview work etc. without problems but only if the 2nd Forms get's showed first :/ I first add items and then update SubItems.Strings[x]

Comment: It doesn't sound as though you are pumping your message queue but it's impossible to say. There's no information here. You need to tell us more. Show more code and let us reproduce this.

Comment: I edited the question. I also use Indy ThreadManagers etc. which should not be a problem tho :/ EDIT: If you could help via TeamViewer, that would be nice :)

Comment: Is all your VCL code running in the main GUI thread?

Comment: It seems you're forcing creation of listview window in your workaround. I'd suggest you to try `HandleNeeded` on the listview (perhaps on SecondWindow before that).

Comment: What's about 'winforms'?

Comment: HandleNeeded that solved the Problem! Thank you so much! The WinForms Tag was a mistake. Sorry about that.

Comment: DO NOT call `HandleNeeded()` in the `OnExecute` event, if you are. Doing so can cause the control's `HWND` to be created in the wrong thread context, rendering the control completely useless.

Comment: Yeah, HandleNeeded() is most definitely not the solution here. You simply must synchronize all GUI code into the main thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calling VCL methods from outside the main GUI thread, i.e. in TMainWindow.ServerSocketExecute. This event executes in a worker thread. Calling VCL/GUI code from a worker thread is simply against the rules of the game. All VCL code **must** execute in the main GUI thread.

So, solve the problem by making sure that all VCL/GUI code executes in the GUI thread. Use the TIdPeerThread.Synchronize() method, or the TIdSync or TIdNotify class to achieve this.

<sub>Thanks to @Remy for supplying the details that I did not know.</sub>

Comment: To elaborate, `TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component. The `OnExecute` event is fired in the context of a worker thread that is managed by the provided `TIdPeerThread` object, not in the context of the main UI thread. VCL UI operations, like adding items to a `TListView`, only work in the context of the main UI thread. To perform UI operations in the `OnExecute` event, you must sync with the main thread using the `TIdPeerThread.Synchronize()` method, or the `TIdSync` or `TIdNotify` class.